# Getting a primary key from 2 login fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I need to get a pk from a table which has three columns, this is wpf using two test boxes of which the input should be in the database

Example

```
1    mo       1234
2    luke     5678 
3    tom      qwert
etc
```

So when I type `tom` in my username box and `qwer` in my password box, I should get 3.

This is the code I have so far

```
string searchdb = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM login
                    WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(searchdb, connection))
{
     connection.Open();

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernametxt.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordtxt.Text);

     int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     if (result > 0)
     {
           int j = result;
           MessageBox.Show("Logged In!");
           entry1 entry1 = new entry1();                            
           entry1.Show();
           this.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: If you want the PK, why are you querying `Count(*)`?

Comment: as @BrootsWaymb said, you are selecting the count of rows, and not the primary key, once you put SELECT PRIMARY_KEY(put the correct name) , the result itself should give you the desired result

Comment: Side note: Always hash the passwords and never use plain text (as passwordtxt.Text); Store user passwords hashed (one-way encryption) via a strong hash function. A search for "C# encrypt passwords" gives a load of examples.

Comment: thanks @JoãoPauloAmorim i got it working.!!

Comment: @xxish glad to help =)

Comment: And for the love of all that's good and holy, [validate your parameters](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).